# How to invoke three finger tap, Quartz Event

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to invoke a three finger tap on OSX. I understand how to use Quartz Event to do a clicks with code similar to this:

```
CGEventRef tempEventForMouseLocation = CGEventCreate(NULL); // don't mix nspoint and cg point...or else
CGPoint point = CGEventGetLocation(tempEventForMouseLocation);
CFRelease(tempEventForMouseLocation); // relese the event

// peform n tap, single finger
CGEventRef singleFinger_nTapEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown, point, kCGMouseButtonLeft);
CGEventSetIntegerValueField(singleFinger_nTapEvent, kCGMouseEventClickState, numTaps); // 1 for single click

for (int i=0; i < numTaps; i++) {
    CGEventSetType(singleFinger_nTapEvent, kCGEventLeftMouseDown);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, singleFinger_nTapEvent);
    CGEventSetType(singleFinger_nTapEvent, kCGEventLeftMouseUp);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, singleFinger_nTapEvent);
}

CFRelease(singleFinger_nTapEvent); // release the event
```

Standard on OSX for a three finger tap is the Quick Look. I would rather not implement the quicklookwithevent  method if I didn't have to, I would rather trigger a three finger tap if possible (and let the OS do that work).

I haven't had much luck searching for this, so any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I'm trying to create the quicklook event but it is giving me errors because while creating it I'm sure I did not enter the parameters correctly. This is what I have right now:

```
NSPoint point = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
NSInteger windowNumber = [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] windowNumber];
NSEvent *quickLookEvent = [NSEvent otherEventWithType:NSEventTypeQuickLook location:point modifierFlags:kNilOptions timestamp:0 windowNumber:windowNumber  context:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] subtype:NSAppKitDefined data1:0 data2:0];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] postEvent:quickLookEvent atStart:NO];
```

Comment: Taps are not clicks. (The user touches the trackpad surface and then removes the touch, but does not push to depress its click mechanism.)  They are not mouse events. They are multi-touch events and there's no support in Quartz for generating them.

Comment: Ahh, so I'll have to work with NSEvent then, as opposed to Quartz Event.

Comment: You won't be able to post `NSEvent`s to other processes. I'm not sure if you can create multi-touch `NSEvent`s either. In short, I don't think it's possible to do what you want without getting into HID drivers or the like.

Comment: Sad face. Well thanks Ken!

Comment: *sigh*, I had a feeling this project was going to spiral deeper into the OS than I wanted. Onto learning about HID drivers!